# mocking setInterval in created hook (vue.js)

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, vue-test-utils

I am trying to mock a `setInterval` inside my `created` hook but no matter what I try
the function is never called. What I have done so far is using `jest.useFakeTimers` and inside
each test I would use `jest.advanceTimersByTime(8000)` to check if my api is being called.
I would appreciate any opinions/help. thanks

my vue file

```js
  created() {
    setInterval(() => this.checkStatus(), 8000)
  },
  methods: {
    async checkStatus() {
      let activated = false
      if (!this.isLoading) {
        this.isLoading = true
        let res = await this.$UserApi.getUserActivateStatus(this.accountId)
        this.isLoading = false
        if (res.success) {
          activated = res.activated
        }
        if (activated) {
          console.log("activated")
        } else {
          console.log("error")
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

my test file

```js
import { shallowMount, config } from "@vue/test-utils"
import Step4 from "../../../login/smart_station/step4"

describe("Step4", () => {
  let wrapper
  const $route = {
    query: {
      account_id: "99"
    }
  }

  const mockGetUserActivateStatus = jest.fn(() =>
    Promise.resolve({ success: true, activated: true })
  )

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = shallowMount(Step4, {
      mocks: {
        $UserApi: {
          getUserActivateStatus: mockGetUserActivateStatus
        }
      }
    })
    jest.useFakeTimers()
  })

  it("activates status every 8secs", async () => {
    jest.advanceTimersByTime(9000)
    expect(mockGetUserActivateStatus).toHaveBeenCalled()
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Jest's [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks) replace the native timer functions like `setInterval` with their own versions that can be controlled.

Your problem is that you are telling Jest to replace these functions **after** your component is created and mounted. Since you're using `setInterval` within your component's `created` hook, this will still be using the real version.

Move the `jest.useFakeTimers()` to the top of the `beforeEach` setup function

```js
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.useFakeTimers()

  wrapper = shallowMount(Step4, {
    mocks: {
      $UserApi: {
        getUserActivateStatus: mockGetUserActivateStatus
      }
    }
  })
})
```